# In the Account detail the list of attachment is not opening in same window

Tags: apex, visualforce

[![This is the link which i click][1]][1][![When i click link it display blank][2]][2]    public with sharing class DisplayProfilePictureController{

```
    public Attachment file{set;get;}
    public Boolean hasPicture{set;get;}
    private String parentId{set;get;}
    public List<Attachment> attList{get;set;}

    List<Account> accounts=new List<Account>();
    List<Opportunity> opps=new List<Opportunity>();

    public DisplayProfilePictureController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    this.parentId = stdController.getId();
    System.debug('&&&&'+parentId);
    this.hasPicture = false;



   attList = [SELECT ParentId, Name, Id, ContentType, BodyLength FROM Attachment 
                                        WHERE ParentId in (Select Id from opportunity where accountId=:this.ParentId)];

    }

 }
```

---

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="DisplayProfilePictureController">
   <apex:form >
        <apex:sectionHeader title="View Attachments"/>
        <apex:pageblock >

            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!attList}" var="a">

                <apex:column headerValue="Parent Id"> 
                 <apex:outputLink value="/{!a.id}">{!a.ParentId}</apex:outputLink>
                 </apex:column>

                 <apex:column headerValue="Name"> 
                 <apex:outputLink value="/{!a.id}">{!a.name}</apex:outputLink>
                 </apex:column>
                 <apex:column headerValue="Body Length"> 
                 <apex:outputLink value="/{!a.id}">{!a.BodyLength}</apex:outputLink>
                 </apex:column>

              </apex:pageblocktable>

        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: In the above code ,In the Account details list of attachment is showed.now problem is that when i click one of these link it is not opening in same section.

Comment: when i right click and it opens in different window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `target="_self"` with you `outputlink`.

```
<script>

    function refreshParent( attId){
         window.parent.location='/'+attId;
    }

</script>


    <apex:outputLink onclick="refreshParent('{!a.id}');" target="_self">{!a.ParentId}</apex:outputLink>
```

As this is a inline VF page then you need `window.parent.location` for this.

Comment: Not working ,when i open the link whole section become blank

Comment: @karuna is this a inline VF page?

Comment: ,i added target="_self" but still not working

Comment: Yes the list of attachment is coming in Account details,where from account layout i added a section and in that visualforce page is added

Comment: @karuna check my updated answer.

Comment: i added script ,but still when i click the link the whole section display blank.But when i right click and open that link in another window it opens fine with detail

Comment: @karuna check if you are getting some exception in console. Also it would be better if you paste a screenshot of blank screen.

Comment: i added the two screenshot where list of attachment is displaying another one when clicking one of link it display blank

Comment: @karuna Isuggest you to disable development Mode. Many of time javascript does not work due to this.

Comment: ,after disabling development Mode it worked thanks for your help